# found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when trying to play a sound

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

I am trying to play a sound in my OS X app which has been built in Swift.

I am getting the following error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

The line of code in question is:

```
let bgMusicURL:NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("emptytrash", withExtension: "aif")!
```

I have the sound located here [image: here]

However when I call my method to prepare and play the sound:

```
 func playSound() {
        let bgMusicURL:NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("emptytrash", withExtension: "aif")!
        backgroundMusicPlayer = try!  AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicURL)
        backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
        backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()    
        backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
    }
```

I get this error. What is going on?

I declare it with this:

```
var backgroundMusicPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

Comment: Is the file actually added to your target bundle? A file that is part of the project doesn't have to be necessarily copied to the bundle.

Comment: Okay how would I add it to the bundle?

Comment: Open the right sidebar in Xcode and select the file, you should then see whether it is added to your main target or not.

Comment: Figured it out, that was it thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file that is part of your project doesn't have to be a part of your target, that means it won't get copied to the application bundle.

To see "Target membership", you can open the sidebar on the right side (File inspector) of the window. See  [Viewing the properties of a File](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-structure_navigator/articles/Viewing_the_Properties_of_a_File.html) for more information.